# Determinant of a $2\times 2$ block matrix with special condition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Can one say something about the determinat of $2n\times2n$ matrix
$$M =\begin{pmatrix} A & B\\ C& D\end{pmatrix},$$
if it is known that

1) $A,B,C,D$ are all $n\times n$ matrices

2) $A$ and $D$ are invertible

3) $\det(B) = \det(C) = 0$ and $B,C$ both have rank 1?

It is well know that $\det(M)=\det(A)\cdot \det(D-CA^{-1}B)$, but what can we tell knowing $\det(B) = \det(C) = 0$?

Comment: You can't really tell anything at all. What kind of answer are you expecting, anyway?

Comment: Some spelling errors, for future reference: determin*ant*, matri*ces*, inver*tible*, and use `\det` instead of just `det`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mistakes. Well, my hope was to simplify general formula for $\det(M)$, but I found counterexamples to all possible reasonable simplifications, so I asked this really thinking someone experienced will tell me "there is nothing you can add".

Comment: without more information than just "$B,C$ aren't invertible", there isn't really anything you can do.  If $B$ and $C$ have a very low rank, that might be another story.  With that, we might be able to come up with a computationally easier (but uglier) formula for $\det(M)$

Comment: Wow, In my case both $B$ and $C$ are NOT invertible, moreother, they both have rank 1. Can you please continue the story?

Comment: Can you please provide some references where I can read how to do it? I am super excited to see that ugly formula for $\det(M)$

Comment: see my answer below.  Wasn't expecting a rank of $1$, that's gold in numerical linear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write 
$$
M = \pmatrix{A&0\\0&D} + \pmatrix{0&B\\C&0} =: P + Q
$$
Of course, we have $\det(P) = \det(AD) = \det(A)\det(D)$.  Because $B$ and $C$ are rank $1$, it is necessarily possible to write $Q$ in the form
$$
Q = UV^T
$$
Where $U,V$ are both $n \times 2$. This is called a [rank factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization).  With that, we can apply the generalized [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) to find that
$$
\det(M) = \det(P + UV^T)  = \det(I + V^TP^{-1}U) \det(P)
$$

---

A bit more specific: if we have rank-1 factorizations $B = u_1v_1^T$ and $C = u_2v_2^T$, then 
$$
\pmatrix{0 & B\\C &0 } = 
\pmatrix{0 & u_1v_1^T\\u_2v_2^T &0 } = \underbrace{\pmatrix{u_1&0\\0 & u_2}}_U \quad \underbrace{\pmatrix{0&v_1^T\\ v_2^T & 0}}_{V^T}
$$
And, with the block matrix structure, we have
$$
P^{-1}U = \pmatrix{A^{-1}u_1 & 0\\0 & D^{-1}u_2}
$$
In the end, we have
$$
\det(M) = \det\pmatrix{1 & v_1^TD^{-1}u_2\\v_2^TA^{-1}u_1 & 1} \det(A)\det(D)
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for you clear answer and for your references. I wish you all the best!

Comment: See also my latest edit. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The derivation of Omnomnomnom's answer can be made shorter if you apply Sylvester determinant theorem directly to the Schur complement. Let $B=u_1v_1^T$ and $C=u_2v_2^T$. Then
\begin{align}
\det(M)
&=\det(A)\det(D-CA^{-1}B)\\
&=\det(A)\det\bigg(D-\underbrace{u_2}_u\,\underbrace{(v_2^TA^{-1}u_1)v_1^T}_{v^T}\bigg)\\
&=\det(A)\left[1-(v_2^TA^{-1}u_1)(v_1^TD^{-1}u_2)\right]\det(D),
\end{align}
where the last line is due to Sylvester determinant theorem $\det(D-uv^T)=(1-v^TD^{-1}u)\det(D)$.

Comment: Nice catch.  The right trick always seems so clear in retrospect.